# Any cheat sheet available that shows UX match between mouse events and touch events?

Tags: web-app, touch-screen, mouse

I am supposed to make a web App UI Design which can be used through PC and Tablet. I am looking for a cheatsheet or link where mouse events and touch events are matched?

Eg. A mouse click on PC is equal to a tap on tablet...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The only actions with true equivalence in both environments are taps and clicks.

Swipes and drag-and-drops aren't the same, because dragging and dropping is much harder ergonomically, so you wouldn't rely on it as you would with swipes. Swipes don't map to mouse movements either, as you can have nonsemantic mouse movements as the user innocently moves the cursor to hit some other target. Pinches and zooms do map, but on desktop, zooms tend to be managed by the host application or OS rather than the webpage in question.

Even if the actions were comparable, most of the time your mobile and desktop experiences are going to differ because the contexts of use are so different. Users' priorities in the different contexts won't be the same, so the UIs won't be the same either.

Answer (score 5):

The interactions aren't necessarily mapped consistently one-to-one across mediums and devices.

For instance, there is no swipe or pinch(typically) via a mouse. Conversely there's no mouseover or right click via touch.

Furthermore, there's things to consider such as keyboard navigation as well as touch pad navigation.

So, short version is that there is no true universal cheat sheet for this.

Because of that, when designing the UI, be sure to use device agnostic terminology. Use 'select' instead of 'click' or 'tap'.

Comment: i understand that we cannot have consistent one-to-one mapping..but wanna know if we follow some specific mapping events if we need one...and may uses same..